# Getting stack alignment error in x86 Assembly on MacOS when making sequential C calls?

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm currently learning x86 assembly on MacOS, and I am getting a stack misalignment error whenever making two C calls.

I have already tried using proper stack padding, making sure to have a stack size of 12 Bytes to satisfy the 16-byte stack alignment when MacOS tacks on its extra push.

I've googled making calls C calls in mac x86 assembly, but I can't seem to find examples that are more than just a call, then exit. I believe there is some stack cleanup that I'm not doing properly after the call that is leaving the stack misaligned, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
    _main:

        # First open the file?
        # int open(const char *path, int flags, ...)
        subl $0x04, %esp            # Pad the stack
        pushl $0x0                  # This is the flag for O_RDONLY
        pushl $path                 # Then add the path

        call _open                  # Make the call to open
        movl %eax, fd               # Put the file descriptor into the fd variable

        # Let's just close the file
        # int close(int fd);
        subl $0x08, %esp            # Stack padding
        pushl $fd                   # Push the file descriptor onto the stack
        call _close                 # Close that bitch

        # Display a nice message and leave
        subl $0x08, %esp            # Buffer da stackaroo
        pushl $end_message          # Put our message on da stack
        call _printf                # Print the message

        # Goodbye :)
        call _exit
```

This should theoretically just open and close a file descriptor, and works when I just open it, but as soon as I add the code to close it (or just the printf code, it fails).

This is the full error that I get from `lldb`:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0xa7aa6bd0 libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_
```

Does anyone see what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The size of the stack is in a way irrelevant to the alignment requirement. The alignment requirement of 16 bytes alignment means that the address the stack starts must be on an address which is evenly dividable by `16`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there any good way to see what the size of the stack is at the end of each call?

Comment: And you probably need a *lot* more space than 12 bytes for the stack. First because the functions you call need space for their local variables, then of course to fit the return address pushed by the `call` instruction, and you need space for the OS to push the stack-frame needed for a system call. No need to minimize it on any PC-like system.

Comment: Most assemblers would have directives for help with alignment. Please read the documentation of the assembler you're using.

Comment: Not actually a stack alignment error, the code confuses the OS too much to produce a good diagnostic.  The best way to find out how to properly call C functions is to use a C compiler.  Look at the assembly listing it generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming the stack is 16-byte aligned again after a call to a C function returns. It's not. It's the same as it was before your `call` instruction, 4 bytes off.

```
_main:
# on entry, %esp is 0x...0 (last digit is 0, 16-byte aligned)
    subl $0x04, %esp            # Pad the stack
# %esp is 0x...c
    pushl $0x0                  # This is the flag for O_RDONLY
# %esp is 0x...8
    pushl $path                 # Then add the path
# %esp is 0x...4
# call will push 4-byte return address, making %esp on entry to open() 0x...0
    call _open                  # Make the call to open
# open()'s ret will pop the 4-byte return address, putting %esp back to 0x...4
    movl %eax, fd               # Put the file descriptor into the fd variable
    subl $0x08, %esp            # Stack padding
# %esp is 0x...c
    pushl $fd                   # Push the file descriptor onto the stack
# %esp is 0x...8
# call will push 4-byte return address, making %esp on entry to close() 0x...4
# that's mis-aligned
    call _close                 # Close that bitch
    ...
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you! So basically I should just be able to `addl $0x4, %esp` after the C call and everything should behave as I expect it to, correct?

Comment: Well, you *could* **subtract** 4 and things would work, but you'd be wasting stack space. You could add 12 (0xc) to restore the stack pointer to what it was when `_main` was entered and that would work without being wasteful. What a C compiler will usually do, though, is at the beginning of the function, subtract enough to hold all locals and the most parameters that any function call will need. Then, it doesn't push or pop, it just writes to, for example, `0(%esp)`, `0x4(%esp)`, etc. for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped a ton! Here is the finished random number generator: https://gist.github.com/NateSeymour/0b3f789ab8b72e8cc1c683dfc06d0b68 :)